# Map key which produces multiple scan codes on Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I own an MSI Laptop which has some special functions on the F keys, for instance, Toggling Touchpad on F4 key.

In Windows, this key is working as expected: enabling/disabling the touchpad. But in Linux (Fedora) it's not working.

`showkey -s` produces the following result when I press the key:

```
0x1d 0xe0 0x5b 0x76 0x9d 0xe0 0xdb 0xf6
```

`showkey` without parameters produces this:

```
keycode  28 release
keycode  29 press
keycode 125 press
keycode  85 press
keycode  29 release
keycode 125 release
keycode  85 release
```

Pretty much the same I've got from `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x7e7, subw 0x0, time 1277257, (692,1239), root:(692,1314),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x7e7, subw 0x0, time 1277259, (692,1239), root:(692,1314),
    state 0x4, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x7e7, subw 0x0, time 1277261, (692,1239), root:(692,1314),
    state 0x44, keycode 93 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x7e7, subw 0x0, time 1277262, (692,1239), root:(692,1314),
    state 0x44, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x7e7, subw 0x0, time 1277265, (692,1239), root:(692,1314),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x7e7, subw 0x0, time 1277266, (692,1239), root:(692,1314),
    state 0x0, keycode 93 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

In total 3 KeyPress events and 3 KeyRelease events.

And `xbindkeys --multikey` gives the following on a single F4 key press:

```
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x44 + c:37
    Control+Mod4 + Control_L
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x40 + c:133
    Mod4 + Super_L
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x0 + c:93
    NoSymbol
```

I tried to use `xbindkeys` using the first portion to remap the key to my liking in .xbindkeysrc file:

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86TouchpadToggle"
    m:0x44 + c:37 + Release
```

But it didn't work.

Please point me in the right direction/tool how to achieve it on Fedora. My first candidate is `xchainkeys` but it's not available in the trusted/Fusion repositories. Is there other ways how to remap the key with a long sequence of scan codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the issue. The key step for the solution was found on the Arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MSI_P15#Keyboard).
It's not exactly the same MSI laptop that I have but it still worked for me.

All I had to do is to assign the keycode 93 to its original function:

> ~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode  93 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
```

And then since I'm using KDE in Shortcuts settings I've mapped the Touchpad Toggle operation to the desired F4 key.

Answer (score 0):

From [Defining keyboard shortcuts involving the Fn key](https://superuser.com/a/439929/1001901) there are
some insigths that may answer to this problem:

> On most systems it is not possible to detect the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key
> itself, but you could try using:
>
> ```
> $ xev | grep --line-buffered keysym
> ```
>
> to find out what keys <kbd>Fn-Left</kbd> and <kbd>Fn-Right</kbd> do
> send.  (The `grep` just reduces the noise.)
>
> If you are lucky, those keypresses will send unimportant keystrokes to
> the machine, which you can then remap.
>
> For example, on my system, `xev` shows that my <kbd>Fn-Left</kbd>
> keypress actually sends an `XF86AudioPrev` event:
>
> ```
> state 0x0, keycode 173 (keysym 0x1008ff16, XF86AudioPrev), same_screen YES,
> ```
>
> I can easily remap this to translate into a <kbd>Home</kbd> key event:
>
> ```
> $ xmodmap -e 'keysym XF86AudioPrev = Home'
> ```
>
> Hopefully you will be able to do the same for End, PageUp and
> PageDown.
>
> Unfortunately if xev does not receive anything unique when you press
> <kbd>Fn-Left</kbd> then you are out of luck.
>
> It's a real shame that <kbd>Fn</kbd> keypresses are not sent directly
> like the other modifier keys are.  If they were, we would have much
> more power to configure their meaning through software.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question is not particularly related to Fn keys, I've updated the original text. It's just an F key, like F1, F2, F3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem on a msi p15 (a10sc) laptop.

I made a script called `toggleTouchpad.sh` mapped to the same key conbination that shows

```
xbindkeys --key
```

when I press the <kbd>F4</kbd> key and changed <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd> to <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd> because is more natural to me pressing in that order (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>)

- The script:

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                            
  touchpadId=$(xinput list | grep -o 'Touchpad.*id=[0-9]*' | awk 'NF{print $NF}' | sed 's/id=//')                                                                                            
  propId=$(xinput list-props $touchpadId | awk '/Device Enabled \([0-9]+\)/{print $3}' | sed 's/[():]//g')                                                                                   
  propVal=$(xinput list-props $touchpadId | awk '/Device Enabled \([0-9]+\)/{print $4}')                                                                                                     

  if [ "$propVal" -eq "1" ]; then                                                                                                                                                            
      xinput set-prop $touchpadId $propId 0                                                                                                                                                  
  else                                                                                                                                                                                       
      xinput set-prop $touchpadId $propId 1                                                                                                                                                  
  fi
  ```
- My `.xbindkeysrc`

  ```
  "toggleTouchpad.sh"                                                                                                                                                                                 
      Control+Mod4 + Control_R
  ```

If you use the script make sure that its taken the touchpad id correctly (I am not a bash expert), I used the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) to do it.

Obviously you can bind the script to any other key combination.

**Notes**

- This not solve the problem of the <kbd>F4</kbd> key but can be useful while  a solution is finding.
- <kbd>Mod4</kbd> is the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key

Comment: it doesn't answer the question but thank you for the script anyway. It can be helpful for someone else. There are several ways to affect the touchpad through the console including the one that I used in my original post.